# Are there any public TypeScript typings (.d.ts) npm package for Blazor's blazor.web.js?

Tags: blazor, typescript-typings

Currently I have to do things like `(window as any).Blazor.navigateTo(...)` and loose all TypeScript type checks in my .ts files for client side of my Blazor SSR project or manually define IBlazor.

As asked in the title, are there any npm package like @types/Blazor.Web or some blazor.web.d.ts I could download and use in my project? All I could find was some blazor interop types.

IBlazor interface for reference:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web.JS/src/GlobalExports.ts#L98